# SharedPreferences called on null flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, sharedpreferences

I build a function that is used to store the token in shared preference and then fetch data from the server when I run my app for the very first time an error appears

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building AdminPage(dirty,
> state: AdminPageState#87bcd): flutter: The method '[]' was called on
> null. flutter: Receiver: null flutter: Tried calling:

and then the app works fine

P.S. my code is that

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getCards(String userid) async {
  BuildContext context;
  String jWTtoken = '';
  try {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    //  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    jWTtoken = prefs.getString('token');
    tokenfoo();
  } catch (e) {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => AuthPage()),
    );
  }

  final Map<String, dynamic> authData = {
    'Userid': '261',
    // 'Email':_formData['Email'],
    // 'Password':_formData['Password'],
  };

  final http.Response response = await http.post(
      'hurl',
      body: json.encode(authData),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jWTtoken
      });

  final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);

  if (responseData["StatusCode"] == 200) {

    null;
  
  } else if (responseData["StatusCode"] == 401) {
    print(responseData);
    Logout();
  } else {
    print(responseData);
    Logout();

    null;
  }
  return responseData;
}
```

anything worng with it?

and in the debug mode the error appears in this line

```
 final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

the error :

> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
> ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ flutter:
> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building AdminPage(dirty,
> state: AdminPageState#7db9a): flutter: The method '[]' was called on
> null. flutter: Receiver: null flutter: Tried calling:  flutter:
> flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: flutter:
>
> ## 0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5) flutter: #1
>
> AdminPageState.build (package:idb/pages/adminpage.dart:63:39) flutter:
>
> ## 2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3809:27) flutter: #3
>
> ComponentElement.performRebuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:15) flutter: #4
> Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
> flutter: #5      ComponentElement._firstBuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5) flutter: #6
> StatefulElement._firstBuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11) flutter: #7
> ComponentElement.mount
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5) flutter: #8
> Element.inflateWidget
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14) flutter: #9
> Element.updateChild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12) flutter: #10
> ComponentElement.performRebuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16) flutter: #11
> Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
> flutter: #12     BuildOwner.buildScope
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2286:33) flutter: #13
> _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:676:20) flutter: #14
> _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
> (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:219:5) flutter: #15
> _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15) flutter: #16
> _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9) flutter: #17
> _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:842:5) flutter: #18
> _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:13) flutter: #19     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:143:3)

Comment: Please post the stack trace !

Comment: how to do that 

Comment: Have you tried removing the final modifier on the line? It makes no sense to make it a final.

Comment: error may be at `jWTtoken = prefs.getString('token')` check for it. And post the complete error you get.

Comment: i updated my question @AmolG

Comment: the error seems to be in `adminpage.dart` file refer line number 63 in adminpage. Is the error occurs continuously or occurs some times only? Can you provide adminpage code?

Comment: it wooorkksss!!! thank you @AmolG

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because jwToken is empty at initialization. Try giving jwToken a string value such as "test".

Comment: The problem in the question was solved, see the comments on the question.

Comment: An answer with **Possibly** and **Try** does not seem like an answer, just a suggestion

Comment: Yes, but finding an answer often involves trying a possible solution and going through the process of elimination.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global class to use globally:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

static Future init() async {
    pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
```